# Mysql backup from command line

Tags: backup

I need to backup a database on a CentOs. I am currently connected to the database. If I run `show tables;` it shows me all tables and so on.

Running the `mysqldump` command just goes to the next line and does nothing. I would like to download that backup file to my computer and use it to recreate the database on another server.

```
mysql> mysqldump oo_db > oo_db_backup_aug_2
    ->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLDump is not an SQL command. You don't run it from inside MySQL. You run it from the command line.

[See here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).